# macOs Android Emulator: qemu-system-i386 - image not found

Tags: android, macos, emulation

When I try to start the emulator from AVD manager, shows a message:

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.3.0 (build_id 7196367) (CL:N/A)
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOUSBHost.framework/Versions/A/IOUSBHost
  Referenced from: /Users/<UserName>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
  Reason: image not found
```

Where is problem ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Same issue here, being poking at it unsuccessful as of yet

Comment: Why is this started happening lately? I have the same problem. 
What's your macOS version?

Comment: how do we fix this? i need help

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the latest Android emulator version installed - `30.5.4`. 
 `SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Android Emulator`

It was happening for me with the previous versions of the emulator.
Now it works as they have released a new update.

Comment: definitely not the problem, i tried all possible versions please help